# Hide a menu bar in some particular users

Tags: reactjs

I want to hide a menu bar if the user is not admin. How to conditionally render the menu bar?

```
{this.state.userName === 'admin' ?
                    <SubMenu className="side-sub-menu" key="6" style={style}
                             title={<a><img src="/assets/settings.png" alt="settings-img"/><span className="nav-text">Settings</span></a>}>
                        <Menu.Item>
                            <Link to='/companies'>
                                <img src="/assets/modules.png" alt="modules-img"/>
                                <span className="nav-text">Companies</span>
                            </Link>
                        </Menu.Item>
 </SubMenu>
                    : ''}
```

Comment: Please check if userName is set correctly. hint (spell mistake, case sensitive.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using conditional (ternary) operator use logical `&&` operator.

```
{ this.state.userName === "admin" && <SubMenu />; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`&&` is considered [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), i.e. the right hand side is not evaluated if the left hand side is false. You can use this to your advantage to render components conditionally.

You can use something like this:

```js
class Test extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { userName } = this.state
    const isAdmin = userName === 'admin'
    return (
      <div>
        {isAdmin && (
          <SubMenu
            className="side-sub-menu"
            key="6"
            style={style}
            title={
              <a>
                <img src="/assets/settings.png" alt="settings-img" />
                <span className="nav-text">Settings</span>
              </a>
            }
          >
            <Menu.Item>
              <Link to="/companies">
                <img src="/assets/modules.png" alt="modules-img" />
                <span className="nav-text">Companies</span>
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
          </SubMenu>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```